# Probability of dependet events

Tags: probability

> We have got 5 real dollar bills and 2 fake dollar bills. Expert can recognize the fake dollar bill with probability of 4/5 (Probability that expert will declare a valid bill as fake is 1/5 = Probability that expert will declare a fake bill as valid is 1/5). Expert took one of that 7 bills and the probability that he claims it to be fake is 8/35. Is it true or false? If its false correct the probability.

Comment: Not sure there is enough information here.  You've given us the probability of a false negative (that is, I believe, you have said that the expert will call the counterfeit bill valid with probability $\frac 15$.  But we also need the probability of a false positive (I.e. what is the probability that the expert will declare a valid bill counterfeit?)

Comment: Probability that expert will declare a valid bill as fake is 1/5 = Probability that expert will declare a fake bill as valid is 1/5

Comment: I have answered your question based on the comment above, but you should add this comment to the question.

Comment: I added it, I though it is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split it into disjoint events, and then add up their probabilities:

- The probability that the expert takes a real bill and claims it to be fake is $\frac57\cdot\frac15=\frac{5}{35}$
- The probability that the expert takes a fake bill and claims it to be fake is $\frac27\cdot\frac45=\frac{8}{35}$

Hence the probability that the expert takes a bill and claims it to be fake is $\frac{5}{35}+\frac{8}{35}=\frac{13}{35}$

Comment: Sir, that is the correct answer.

Comment: @MichaelHalinár: You're welcome sir! Feel free to accept this answer :) BTW, I have answered your question based on the comment that you added, but you should add this comment to the question.